# How to alter a primary key in an SQL Server 2005 database without losing any data?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have one table in my database that has a primary key and its data type is varchar(10) but it stores only 5 char, so I want to change its data type from varchar(10) to varchar(5) without losing any data.

Currently I'm creating a temp table, moving data from the original table to the temp table, then altering it, and lastly restoring the data from temp to the main table again.

I want to know if there is another solution for this problem?

Comment: Why bother? It's not like a varchar(5) uses less storage space than a varchar(10) in just about every storage engine out there.

Comment: @kquinn: au contraire - every DBMS I know would use less space for a VARCHAR(5) than for a VARCHAR(10).  In the DBMS I know best, the overhead would increase from 9% to 17% (because there's one byte used to store the actual length); I'd probably use a CHAR(5), because the waste would be minimal.

Comment: Agreed, CHAR(5) sounds best here... but in both MySQL and PostgreSQL, VARCHAR(5) and VARCHAR(10) will use the same amount of storage for, say, the string 'ABCD'. In PG it's 5 bytes: one length byte (4 if length > 126) plus four data (I don't *think* strings are stored null-terminated; the docs do not say but suggest they are not). IIRC MySQL is the same way, though it might use a 2-byte length header. In both cases, VARCHAR(5) and VARCHAR(10) will use the same space on disk for the same string.

Comment: @kquinn: having revisited this question - I see what you are driving at, and yes the actual disk allocated for VARCHAR(10) storing 5 bytes and for VARCHAR(5) storing 5 bytes would usually be the same. The space allocation might be different in general (marginal in this case). Again, one system I know would ensure that there is enough space for a row of the maximum size on the page, and it would use a different page if there was not enough space.  This matters with many variable length fields that are dramatically overlong (eg 6 fields of VARCHAR(255) when the maximum actual length is only 32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most DBMS, running a simple ALTER TABLE statement would do the whole job in one go, not losing any data.  Are you sure the MS SQL Server doesn't support that?  (If not, maybe you need a better DBMS - but I don't think that'll be the problem.)

Having seen a multi-step operation outlined, I'm puzzled.  In the DBMS I use mainly, all that would be necessary is:

```
ALTER TABLE WhatEver MODIFY pkcolumn VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL;
```

It could even be an 'in place alter'; it would appear to complete almost immediately, even though the actual change would take place over a long time as the actual rows were altered.  (OK; actually for a VARCHAR field that might not occur; for a CHAR field - which would be a decent option when the length is only 5 or 10 bytes - it would be an 'in place alter'.)

Answer (score 1):

I had to this for db2 database. These were the steps suggested by the DBA:

1. Drop dependent objects such as views or procs...Pls. keep a copy of ddl before doing drops
2. Rename existing table to may be _old
3. Create table with correct structure.
4. Perform runstats on _old table
5. Load data from _old table to this new table. Load using identity override flag if you want to preserve identity columns
6. Recreate view and procs
7. Rebind all dependent procs.

You can omit step 4 & 7 if it is db2 specific. Additionally,if there is no prob in SQLServer you can omit dropping and re-creating dependent objects.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specify that you're using SQL Server, that change can and should be done using the design tools.

Start the Management Studio program and connect to the server. Then open up the database in question and find the table.

Right-click on the table and select Design, and then in that view, do the changes.

You now have two choices:

1. You can click on the Save button, and MS SQL Server will script and execute the necessary changes for you
2. or, you can use the Generate Change Script button. In my IDE, this button is the leftmost button on the same toolbar as the key/constraint buttons (not the same toolbar that has the Save button)

If you use the latter function, you will see the script code in a dialog, and can optionally save it to disk. This allows you to get an overview of what will happen should you want to execute it.

The problem with changing the primary key is that all references from other tables in to to that primary key needs to be dropped first, and recreated afterwards, and the SQL Server Management Studio program is smart enough to generate (at least in 99% of the cases) all the SQL you need, in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be creating a table which has a identity int primary key and use your varchar field as a unique alternative natural key for your database.

I know it means that you have to alter any other foreign keys pointing there, but if you are already doing the work you describe, I would go the full hog.

IMHO

Comment: -1: Not every table needs a surrogate key. I am no Celko -- I do recognize their advantages and use them where appropriate, which is much of the time -- but natural keys have several advantages. Blind use and recommendation of autoincrementing surrogate keys is just silly.

Comment: I was indicating to use the surrogate key to replace the current key being used as a primary key so it could be retained if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for me the must valuable method I found is to create a backup table with the following expression:

```
SELECT *
INTO your_table_name_backup 
FROM your_table_name_original
```

This will generate, automatically, a copy of your table with name `your_table_name_backup`

You are now able to change the original table  `(your_table_name_original`) with a drop and create.

After this do

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name_original SELECT * FROM your_table_name_backup
```

And there you go no data loss and new table field types or constrains inserted :)

#### Notes:

I add to write this because no one refers that MSQLMS as some stresses with changing tables without a drop and create, which you can see as a beautiful message coming out when you use designer to change a field type for example. I don't understand why they let you open the designer and actually edit fields types if the end you get a message like this operation is not allowed yadayadayada...

If anyone knows a simpler way just mention it, hope it helps someone...

Answer (score -2):

The general idea is laid out below.  Dont forget to back up your DB first.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD tempColumn VARCHAR(5)

UPDATE tableName SET tempColumn = pkColumn

-- Do this for all constraints

ALTER TABLE tableName DROP CONSTRAINT pkConstraint

ALTER TABLE tableName DROP COLUMN pkColumn

ALTER TABLE tableName ADD pkColumn VARCHAR(5)

UPDATE tableName SET pkColumn = tempColumn

ALTER TABLE tableName DROP COLUMN tempColumn
```

Comment: Are you sure it needs to be this complex?  Really sure?

Comment: Nope.  It doesn't usually have to be that difficult.  But the guy asked here.. wasting our valuable time instead of just reading the docs.  So I don;t mind making him do a little extra work.  Perhaps it will spur him to use his own mind and look for a simpler solution.